# Angular - Why the data I want to display is present but not displayed in view?

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor

**EDIT:**

As pointed by @Mathias in the comments, it's the following `*ngIf` that is not working:

```
(*ngIf="currentUsername == chat.senderUsername else elseBlock1")
```

But I can't see why it's not working, because the currentUsername and the chat.senderUsername both exists, not null and are very the same.
I'm quite lost :/

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I'm new to Angular6 and I'm struggling for hours on an issue, in a `*ngFor`, all my datas are displayed except the username of the receiver/sender, even though they are both present in my `NmChatRequest` entity.

I tried to put ng-template tags around b tags, with or without `?` operator, e.g. `{{chat?.senderUsername}}` in the view, everything and nothing worked. I'm quite lost here, any help would be welcome.

As you can see in the console the required datas `senderUsername` and `receiverUsername` are present and not null, see the screenshot of the developer console:

[image]

Here's the rendering:

[image]

My view is as follow:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let chat of chats">
        <ion-item (click)="goToChat(chat?.id)">
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img *ngIf="currentImageUrl == chat.senderImageUrl else elseBlock" src="{{chat?.receiverImageUrl}}">
            <ng-template #elseBlock>
              <img src="{{chat?.senderImageUrl}}">
            </ng-template>
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>
            <ng-template *ngIf="currentUsername == chat.senderUsername else elseBlock1">
              <ng-template *ngIf="chat?.senderRead == false else elseBlock2">
                <b>{{chat.receiverUsername}}</b>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template #elseBlock2>{{chat.receiverUsername}}</ng-template>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #elseBlock1>
              <ng-template *ngIf="chat?.receiverRead == false else elseBlock3">
                <b>{{chat.senderUsername}}</b>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template #elseBlock3>{{chat.senderUsername}}</ng-template>
            </ng-template>
          </h2>
          <p>{{chat?.lastMessage}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who will take the time to read/answer my post.

Comment: Are you sure this ngIf (*ngIf="currentUsername == chat.senderUsername else elseBlock1") is working? - If you put dummy text inside where you expect it, does it display?

Comment: You're right, it's totally not working, didn't check this, but I can't see why...

Comment: For an obscure reason, when I changed the ```ng-template``` tag of this ngIf to ```ng-container```, it worked. Does anybody has an explanation ?

Comment: Thanks anyway, now it works well ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-template` is supposed to be used as a template reference not a container. You put code inside it and then display it somewhere else by referencing the template(like in the `else` of an `*ngIf`).
If you only want to apply a directive such as `*ngIf` without wrapping your elements in a `<div *ngIf="...">` you have to use `ng-container`.

The normal way to use `*ngIf ... else` is

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition; else temp>Stuff</ng-container>
<ng-template #temp>This doesn't get rendered on its own, only if referenced</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

For an obscure reason, when I changed the `ng-template` tag of this ngIf to `ng-container`, it worked. Does anybody has an explanation ?
Now it's working but I don't really understand the mechanics under this issue.
Thanks to @Mathias for putting me in the right way.